# Prove or disprove $ABA^{T} = AC$ implies $BA^{T} =C$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose A is $m \times n$ non-zero matrix, $B$ is $n \times n$ of full rank and $C$ is $n \times m$ of full column rank. Can we prove or disprove that $ABA^{T} = AC$ implies that $C = BA^{T}$.

Note: Only $B$ is a square matrix. Rest are rectangular matrices with $m < n$.

Comment: $m=n, A=0, B=C=I$ is a counterexample.

Comment: Are $A$ and $A'$ related here?

Comment: Yes. $A'$ is the transpose of $A$.

Comment: If $A$ is invertible then the statement is true. If $A$ is not invertible, then than is when you have a problem.

Comment: @shani You need to define $A'$ in your question. Or even use $A^T$ instead, which I think would be more likely understood.

Comment: @saulspatz: A is a non-zero matrix. I have added it the question now.

Answer (score 4):

Set $A=\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$,
$B=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$,
$C=\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 3\end{pmatrix}$.

Then $ABA^T=AA^T=2=AC$ but $BA^T=A^T\neq C$.

Comment: @ ChoF btw. I upgrade another more challenging but related problem, may be you also can prove it.  The next level challenging, will you also obtain https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2733426

Answer (score 0):

$A=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$, $B=C=I_{2}$

$ABA^{T}=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}=AC$ but $BA^{T}=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\neq C$

Comment: Except $B$, none of them are square matrices.

Comment: You did not restrict that $m\neq n$.

Comment: I'll mention it in the question. Thanks.